# Can't submit my form when two <option> have the same value

Tags: php, html

**EDIT : I have analyzed the problem incorrectly, all values ​​equal to 0 are problematic. You are right, the problem seems to come from the function, do you know how to improve that function ?**

I have a problem on my website.

To contextualize, I created a web page that allows the administrator to add a new member to the database. We can customize the fields (name, firstname, age, ...).

But I have a problem with my *select option* fields.

```
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">

        <!-- other input type text fields -->

        <label for="ban">Banissement</label>
        <select name="ban">
            <option value="0" selected>Non</option>
            <option value="1">Oui</option>
        </select>

        <label for="role">Rôle</label>
        <select name="role">
            <option value="0" selected>Aucun (membre classique)</option>
            <option value="1">Modérateur</option>
            <option value="2">Administrateur</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="register_new_user" value="Créer ce membre" />
    </form>
```

By validating the form, I check if the fields "ban" and "role" are filled. But, if these two have an identical value (if **$_POST['ban'] == 1** and if **$_POST['role'] == 1**), then my page acts as if these two fields have not been filled.

However, if the two fields are different (**$_POST['ban'] == 0** and **$_POST['role'] == 1**) then there is no problem, the two fields are well filled and the code still running...

Here you can see the PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['register_new_user'])) {
    if(not_empty(['firstname','lastname','pseudo','email','password','password_confirm','code','city','score','banque','sortPref','notimeout','ban','role'])) {

        // Sending to the database

    }
}
```

...with the function *not_empty()* I use to check if the fields are filled.

```
if(!function_exists('not_empty')){
    function not_empty($fields = []){
        if(count($fields) != 0){
            foreach($fields as $field){
                if(empty($_POST[$field]) || trim($_POST[$field]) == ""){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I forced to use different values ​​for the whole of my form?

Comment: Your not_empty logic seems flawed given your values.  `empty($_POST[$field])` will return true for `0`, causing not_empty to return false.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php to reinforce @Devon 's Theory

Comment: No, you are not forced to use different values. As long as each control has a distinct `name` they will not interfere with each other at all. So, beyond what has already been said about your use of `empty`, it seems the problem is in some code not shown here, (although that `empty` problem is likely to be related.)

Comment: Really, I am surprised to hear that it works with `$_POST['ban'] == 0`.

Comment: Empty treat 0 in your select option value as empty thus everytime you select 0 as a value it always gave you "return false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantage of `empty` is that it checks that a variable/key is set at the same time it checks that its value is equivalent to `false` (which includes "0"; see [Converting to Boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) without causing an undefined notice. With what you're doing here, you should be able to just use `isset` instead. This will check that the variable is set, which will keep the next part from throwing a notice if it isn't, and the next part will make sure it has a value (including zeroes).

```
if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || trim($_POST[$field]) == "") {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function not_empty($fields = []) {

    foreach($fields AS $key) {

        // Check is set
        if(!isset($_REQUEST[$key]))
            return false;

        $input = $_REQUEST[$key];

        // Check not null value
        if(is_null($input))
            return false;

        // If is array of list items check at least one is selected
        if(is_array($input) && count($input) === 0)
            return false;

        // Must be string or number, trim white sapce
        $input = trim($input);

        // If is valid number continue iteration
        if(is_numeric($input))
            continue;

        // Must be a string, check length is more than zero
        if(strlen($input) === 0)
            return false;

    }

    return true;

}
```

**Why [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) can work against you on their own**

Function **empty** will return **true** for the following value cases:

- Variable, Array Key, Object Key is not declared.
- is **null**
- is empty/zero length string ( **''** )
- is **false**
- is **0** (zero)

Select options with value of an integer zero will be incorrectly evaluated as empty true in your use case.

Function **isset** will return **true** if the Variable, Array Key, Object Key is declared at all, even if it's value returns true with function empty()...

- true if **null**
- true if empty/zero length string ( **''** )
- true if **false**
- true if **0** (zero)

So this makes checking if a value is an undesired blank value quite tricky.
You can suppress these complications by taking these facts into consideration and choose more wisely values to work with that favor less complicated code.

Also note that I have not bothered to check if **$fields** has any items in it's array, the for each loop will not be ran and will not throw an error as long as an empty array is passed.

The *fewer conditional* `if` *statements* you put in your code the better it can perform, always experiment.

You are always better off passing a value as an expected type even if it is an empty array rather than making values NULL.

> NULL checking is bad for your code and NULL setting is not always
>   necessary.